# How to return array of class ojects converted to Json

Tags: python, flask

I have a class `Student`, then I have list of these students and that I am trying to return:

```
import json
import uuid

class Student:
    def __init__(self, firstname : str, lastname : str, fathername : str):
        self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.fathername = fathername

    def __str__(self):
        return f'id:{self.id} ' \
               f'Firstname: {self.firstname}; ' \
               f'Lastname: {self.lastname}; ' \
               f'Fathername: {self.fathername}' \
               f'Group: {self.group}; '
    
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, indent=4)

list = []
student = Student("Vic", "Jeff", "Methon")
list.append(student.toJSON()) # Object of type Student is not JSON serializable
list.append(student.toJSON())
print(json.dumps(list))
```

I am not getting what I want:

```
["{\n\"id\": \"f697b63d26264b02bc9c674c235c9e73\",\n\"firstname\": \"Vic\",\n\"lastname\": \"Jeff\",\n\"fathername\": \"Methon\"\n}", "{\n\"id\": \"f697b63d26264b02bc9c674c235c9e73\",\n\"firstname\": \"Vic\",\n\"lastname\": \"Jeff\",\n\"fathername\": \"Methon\"\n}"]
```

How do I get it to look like this?

```
{
    "Student": [
        {
            "id": "f697b63d26264b02bc9c674c235c9e73",
            "firstname": "Vic",
            "lastname": "Jeff",
            "fathername": "Methon"
        },
        {
            "id": "f697b63d26264b02bc9c674c235c9e73",
            "firstname": "Vic",
            "lastname": "Jeff",
            "fathername": "Methon"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Dumping to JSON is the very last step, after you assembled the object as a Python structure, e.g. a list of dictionaries.

Comment: `toJSON` is a bad idea because `indent=4` is not part of the standard - you're pretty-printing it, basically. Just send back [`jsonify()`](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/flask.jsonify.html)

Comment: iam cant bumb later because "Object of type Student is not JSON serializable" error

Comment: @Jeffi do as Klaus suggests, but provide the default arg (as you do in toJSON). The default function is used whenever the serialiser finds an object it doesn't know how to serialise. default should provide a json-esque type eg object/dict, array/list number/(int/float), etc...

Comment: Don't edit the question with the solution.  Accept an answer below, or write your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put JSON data in a list, and then JSON it again.  Instead, define a custom [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) that understands `Student` objects.  Then the list can contain `Student` objects directly:

```py
import json
import uuid
from pprint import pprint

class StudentEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Student): # if it is a Student object...
            return obj.__dict__      #   return something that is JSON serializable
        return super().default(obj)

class Student:
    def __init__(self, firstname : str, lastname : str, fathername : str):
        self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.fathername = fathername

    def __repr__(self):  # Better choice than __str__.  __str__ uses __repr__ if not defined.
        return (f'Student(id={self.id!r}, '
                f'Firstname={self.firstname!r}, '
                f'Lastname={self.lastname!r}, '
                f'Fathername={self.fathername!r})')
    
students = []  # don't use "list" as a variable. It shadows the "list" type.
students.append(Student('Vic', 'Jeff', 'Methon'))
students.append(Student('John', 'Doe', 'Mark'))
pprint(students)
print()
print(json.dumps({'Student':students}, indent=4, cls=StudentEncoder))
```

Output:

```
[Student(id='d70b5e475fbf430da57795d6885c5370', Firstname='Vic', Lastname='Jeff', Fathername='Methon'),
 Student(id='a8da47a353184b9d910cfb174a47d28d', Firstname='John', Lastname='Doe', Fathername='Mark')]

{
    "Student": [
        {
            "id": "d70b5e475fbf430da57795d6885c5370",
            "firstname": "Vic",
            "lastname": "Jeff",
            "fathername": "Methon"
        },
        {
            "id": "a8da47a353184b9d910cfb174a47d28d",
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Doe",
            "fathername": "Mark"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remember the output you are building, from individual JSONs (strings) is a string, not a list.

```py
import uuid
import json

class Student:
    def __init__(self, firstname : str, lastname : str, fathername : str):
        self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.fathername = fathername

    def __str__(self):
        return f'id:{self.id} ' \
               f'Firstname: {self.firstname}; ' \
               f'Lastname: {self.lastname}; ' \
               f'Fathername: {self.fathername}' \
               f'Group: {self.group}; '
    
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, indent=4)

studentsJSON = "["
student = Student("Vic", "Jeff", "Methon")
studentsJSON += student.toJSON()
studentsJSON +="," 
studentsJSON += student.toJSON()
studentsJSON +="]" 

exactlyWhatYouAmNeed = { "Student": json.loads(studentsJSON) }
print(json.dumps(exactlyWhatYouAmNeed,indent=4))
```

#### Result

You have added the same student twice, so you will get this:

```
{
    "Student": [
        {
            "id": "cf64e424db8448489358f5b243175016",
            "firstname": "Vic",
            "lastname": "Jeff",
            "fathername": "Methon"
        },
        {
            "id": "cf64e424db8448489358f5b243175016",
            "firstname": "Vic",
            "lastname": "Jeff",
            "fathername": "Methon"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Iam need exactly this json, like in my question in the end. Not string like that

Comment: not at all what iam need
{"Student": "{\n \"id\": \"41968ad97c564743b5fe4f83479ab4d4\",\n \"firstname\": \"Vic\",\n \"lastname\": \"Jeff\",\n \"fathername\": \"Methon\"\n}{\n \"id\": \"41968ad97c564743b5fe4f83479ab4d4\",\n \"firstname\": \"Vic\",\n \"lastname\": \"Jeff\",\n \"fathername\": \"Methon\"\n}"}
still what i got before.

Comment: OK Iam have updated - try again?